# Connection Pooling with Apache DBCP (Java 1.6)

Tags: java, connection-pooling, java-6, apache-commons-dbcp

Need some advice on a good solution for Connection Pooling for a stand alone Java application. The back-end database may vary, therefore I need a generic solution (versus database specific Connection Pooling)

The project I'm working on currently uses snaq (www.snaq.net), but I've seen some flakiness and after doing a bit of searching, I'm thinking about going with Apache DBCP. Of course I've found a million different ways to implement it, but a lot of examples are incompatible with Java 1.6 (which is a must have requirement).

So looks like I'll have to go with Apache Commons DBCP 1.4. I'm mainly looking for some advice on the best implementation for this API. I am currently learning towards example 10 on the following url (https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource)

This is my first time working with implementing a DataSource/ConnectionPool in a stand alone app. Up until now I've always been able to let my application server handle my datasource and connection pooling. I inherited the current application I'm working on and snaq is what it was setup to use. That API has been sunset, however, so I'd like to go with something a bit more industry standard.

I'm not looking for anything overly complicated. I need to support about 150-200 connection requests that occur pretty quickly at startup and then on a continual basis probably 50-100 connection requests every 2-3 minutes.

Thanks in advance for any advice/good examples to follow!

Comment: [HikariCP](http://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch...interesting....checking that out now :D thx!